# Remove Woocommerce sidebar from any theme

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, sidebar, wordpress-hook

I'm using WordPress 4.9.4 running Twenty Seventeen Child Theme theme with Woocommerce Version 3.3.4. I am trying to remove the sidebar…  I have tried using this:

```
remove_action('woocommerce_sidebar','woocommerce_get_sidebar',10);
```

But haven't found the right one yet.

How do I remove all sidebars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best and simple way **that works with all themes** is to use the `get_sidebar` Wordpress action hook this way:

```
add_action( 'get_sidebar', 'remove_woocommerce_sidebar', 1, 1 );
function remove_woocommerce_sidebar( $name ){
    if ( is_woocommerce() && empty( $name ) )
        exit();
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).* Tested and works.

> You might need to make some CSS changes on some html related containers

**This code works on any theme** as all themes use `get_sidebar()` Wordpress function for sidebars (even for Woocommerce sidebar) and `get_sidebar` action hook is located inside this function code.

Comment: No. BAD. This stops the rest of the hooks lifecyle hooks

Answer (score 1):

WooCommerce ads the side bar in code directed at this specific theme, in class WC_Twenty_Seventeen
/**
     * Close the Twenty Seventeen wrapper.
     */

```
public static function output_content_wrapper_end() {
        echo '</main>';
        echo '</div>';
        get_sidebar();
        echo '</div>';
    }
```

I used this code to replace that function

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content', array( 'WC_Twenty_Seventeen', 'output_content_wrapper_end' ), 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content', 'custom_output_content_wrapper_end', 10 );
```

/**
     * Close the Twenty Seventeen wrapper.
     */

```
function custom_output_content_wrapper_end() {
        echo '</main>';
        echo '</div>'; 
        echo '</div>';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `is_active_sidebar` hook - this should work in **any** theme as it's core WordPress functionality:

```php
function remove_wc_sidebar_always( $array ) {
  return false;
}
add_filter( 'is_active_sidebar', 'remove_wc_sidebar_always', 10, 2 );
```

You can also use conditional statements to only hide the sidebar on certain pages, e.g. on Product pages:

```php
function remove_wc_sidebar_conditional( $array ) {

  // Hide sidebar on product pages by returning false
  if ( is_product() )
    return false;

  // Otherwise, return the original array parameter to keep the sidebar
  return $array;
}

add_filter( 'is_active_sidebar', 'remove_wc_sidebar_conditional', 10, 2 );
```