# Removing the WooCommerce sidebar the correct way - TwentySeventeen?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, wordpress-hook

I'm working on a project that is running of a child theme of TwentySeventeen and whilst the rest of the site doesn't have a sidebar, WooCommerce seems to have it.

For example, the shop page has it - I have tried a few things already and none work without caveats or didn't work at all:

I tried copying `archive-product.php` to my theme dir in `woocommerce/archive-product.php` and removing the below:

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content' );
```

This didn't work.

I then tried doing:

```
remove_action('woocommerce_sidebar','woocommerce_get_sidebar',10);
```

...this didn't work either.

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49522275/472501) and it worked, but didn't make the page full width (still had space for the sidebar) and a comment on the answer noted using that method isn't a great idea.

I also found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53031314/472501) but it involves adding CSS, something I'd like to avoid as it isn't the most robust method in-case class names change in the future etc...

Isn't there a *proper* way of doing this without potential side affects?

Comment: ...and this was voted down, why!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of Mannu saraswat's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58351269/472501) and some fiddling around I came up with a solution:

```
// Remove the sidebar
add_action('get_header', 'blm_wc_remove_sidebar_check', 10);

// Removes the sidebar

function blm_wc_remove_sidebar($index) {
    return false;
}

// Check to see if we're on a WooCommerce page and if so, remove the sidebar

function blm_wc_remove_sidebar_check() {
    if ( is_woocommerce() ) {
        add_filter('is_active_sidebar', 'blm_wc_remove_sidebar', 10, 1);
    }
}
```

This avoids having to do the `is_active_sidebar` check / filter addition on non-WooCommerce pages.

Maybe there is a cleaner way to do this, but this worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

Please, add this code to your functions.php

For remove only woocommerce side bar

```
 function disable_woo_commerce_sidebar_mms() {
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_sidebar', 'woocommerce_get_sidebar', 10); 
    }
    add_action('init', 'disable_woo_commerce_sidebar_mms')
```

for remove all side bars

```
function remove_sidebar_mms() {
        return false;
    }

    add_filter( 'is_active_sidebar', 'remove_sidebar_mms', 10, 2 );
```

OR

You can try this with to increase the priority hope fully its work

```
remove_action('woocommerce_sidebar','woocommerce_get_sidebar',25);
```

Comment: First option worked great - thank you very much. Will award bounty when able.

Comment: Just noticed this has a bad side affect - it removes the sidebar in ALL pages, not just WooCommerce ones; in other words, there were pages where we wanted the sidebar to remain, but it removed those too. I am unsure how to change this so it returns the expected value when it's not WooCommerce. I know you can do a check for WC pages, but how do you work out what to return when it's not? Returning `true` isn't correct - you have to return the correct expected staus; and obviously doing `return is_active_sidebar($index)` will end up causing an infinite loop. :(

Comment: Okay Sorry to hear that  I have edited my answer as well please try this hopefully it will work for you as you want –

Comment: welcome @PonzioPilato hit upvote so it can help others as well...